# Adicionar ao carrinho magento

Tags: magento

Estou criando um módulo para o magento em que você pode colocar custom options no produtos simples dentro do agrupado.

Só que não estou conseguindo trazer os valores escolhidos pelo usuário.

```
$dataEntrega = array(
                'label'                    => 'Data',
                'option_value'             => 
                'value'                    => 
                'print_value'              => 
            );
            $saborProduto = array(
                'label'                    => 'Sabor',
                'option_value'             => 
                'value'                    => 
                'print_value'              => 
            );
            $value = array('data_entrega'=> $dataEntrega, 'sabor' => $saborProduto);
            $value = serialize($value);
            $_item->addOption(array('code'=> 'additional_options', 'product_id'=> $_item->getProductId(), 'value'=> $value));
            $_item->save();
```

Comment: Seria interessante adicionar um trecho do código que você está tentando.

Comment: Adicionei aqui Fagner.